# How to fatch data from firebase database with model class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to fetch data from firbase database with model class ?

[image]

Comment: So what you want to create, a model class that contains 2 fields, key and word?

Answer (score 1):

Your model , according to the data you want to retrieve should be like this (assuming you only want the key and word)

```
 public class Model {

    private String key;
    private String word;
    private String baseText;
    private String mainText;
    private String type;
    private String url;

    public Model() {
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getBaseText() {
        return baseText;
    }

    public void setBaseText(String baseText) {
        this.baseText = baseText;
    }

    public String getMainText() {
        return mainText;
    }

    public void setMainText(String mainText) {
        this.mainText = mainText;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Then , you can get that data doing this

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Model model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
    log.d("Key: "+model.getKey() + " word: " + model.getWord());
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Where `ref` is your `DatabaseReference` at the node you want to pull the data

Refer to this link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=en#section-start

Comment: i don't want to key and word but whole card arraylist model

Comment: I just edited my answer, then you can log the results the same way

Comment: Saillen thanks for answer but not work key and word are array of hurigna

Comment: just use it with the reference you want to have your data

Answer (score 1):

Let ref be your DatabaseReference then addValueEventListener

Example:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
       DataModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataModel.class);
    }
}
```

The same thing can be done with any class, like if you want to get an output of

```
String -> getValue(String.class)
Integer -> getValue(Integer.class)
```